# How can I remove screwless DVI adapter?

Tags: graphics-card, dvi, adapter

I have a DVI to VGA adapter, pictured here:

[image]

The problem is that the adapter does not have any screws or convenient ways to unscrew it, except for lousy side unscrew mechanisms. The sides have been worn and it's now impossible to unscrew one side. How can I get it out in any other way?

Answer (score 0):

I assume you do not need that adapter anymore (it wouldnt make sense to unplug it just to keep using that worn out thing).
Break the case and see if you can continue from there. Just make sure not do damage anything else, as it is still plugged in.
You could try a saw. You could also try melting the case, but that might not be the best idea.